# Using a Deedle Data frame

Tags: f#, deedle

I'm new to F# and would like to convert my code below to output a deedle data frame or even convert the output array into a data frame.

```
let GetDataBitstamp() =
    async {
        let! csv = sprintf "http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/trades.csv?symbol=bitstampUSD" |> fetch
        return
            [|
                for row in csv.Split([|'\n'|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) do
                    match row.Split([|','|]) with
                    | [|d; p; v |]-> yield (d,p)
                    | _ -> yield! [||]
            |] |> Map.ofArray
    } |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me see code below:

```
module may =
   let simples() =
          let time,price =Map.toArray(Bitcharts.GetDataBitstamp())|> Array.unzip
          time, price
```

The next step is to put the time, price arrays into the data series:

```
let df1 : Frame<int, string> = frame[]
let d,a = may.simples()
df1.AddSeries("ts",d)
df1.AddSeries("price",a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct deedle data frame directly from CSV file using

```
Frame.ReadCsv("csvPath")
```

Comment: Although, I think this might not work with web URLs at the moment, so you might need to download the file before reading it...

Comment: No this does not work on web urls, could I not convert the MapofArray to a deedle file. I wanted to keep this all in memory

Comment: I thought I could possibly do something like let deedleData(datb:Array) = let filtered = Frame.addSeries(datb).However this doesn't work as I have a type issue. My datb is of type string*string.